# How to use a encoded Docx?(unzip)

Tags: java, base64, docx, unzip

**HI**
 so my code works like this, I get a docx and a folder to put the unzip files,

```
String templateLocation = "//path"; //this is where the document is located 
String AUX = "//path";   //this is a aux folder that's get the unzip files
unzip(new File(templateLocation), new File(AUX));
```

and the method unzip is

```
private static void unzip(File zipfile, File directory) throws IOException {

    ZipFile zfile = new ZipFile(zipfile);
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zfile.entries();

    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
      ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
      File file = new File(directory, entry.getName());
      if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        file.mkdirs();
      } 
      else {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        InputStream in = zfile.getInputStream(entry);
        try {
          copy(in, file);
        } 
        finally {
          in.close();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

the thing is that i need to use a external docx that's in Base64
but how? 
attempt with this

```
     String wordx = "DocxInBase64";
     byte[] dataFileWord = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(wordx);
     String dataw = new String(dataFileWord,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But im getting something that looks like corrupted

*PK����Xs���g����l}'_B�R;�q�u@��.�����~�Hwx�=��4��������pv�{3o�'M,���b���wi�O���0��E]}`�x��?...*

any ideas to start with? 
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache POI to parse word files.
http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html